# NHibernate. Order by function result

Tags: nhibernate, sql-order-by

I need NHibernate to perform such query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users
ORDER BY Func(FirstName, LastName)
```

Standart NHibernate `Order` class doesn't allow to do this. Is there any another way?
The fact is, named queries and HQL don't fit as a solution.

**EDIT:** I found, that it is possible to do on SQL:

```
SELECT *, Func(FirstName, LastName) AS FullName 
FROM Users
ORDER BY FullName
```

So, maybe it is possible to add extra field to criteria (or may be projection), like in this example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to create a 'full name', to order by two columns. You can do it like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users
ORDER BY FirstName, LastName
```

-Edit

Or if you want to define the ordering you can include 'asc/desc' after each column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users
ORDER BY FirstName DESC, LastName ASC
```

-End Edit

As for ordering in NHibernate, if you're using QueryOver, you can do:

```
var result = Session.QueryOver<Users>()
                    .OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).Desc
                    .ThenBy(x => x.LastName).Desc
                    .List();
```

As for Criteria, I think (not 100% sure) you can do:

```
var result = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Users))
                    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("FirstName"))
                    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("LastName"))
                    .List<Users>();
```

Comment: The matter is I shoud use special SQL function to perform full user name in right format.

Comment: Then your only way of doing it is to use HQL or SQL. Your example looked like you were just using a function to concatenate FirstName and LastName together.

Comment: You can register a custom SQL function and use that to do the ordering perhaps. Not pretty if it works though. Other option would be to use a Computed Column to use as an orderby column only.

Comment: I think you can only use them in HQL queries tho.

Comment: You can use sql functions with the criteria api.